# How does value matching in awk work?

Tags: macos, bash, awk

I have got a csv file, it has various columns, one of these columns is a Date column, so for a given date, I want to fetch all of the records from the csv, the reason that I cant use grep is that that date might be there in some other column and I dont want that.

So far this is what I have got,

Date is this format:

```
sed 's/\"//g' kk.csv | awk -F ',' '{print $4}'   '$4 ~ /^2012.*/'
```

First I am removing all of the "" quotes, then I have specified the separator ',' then I am applying the condition on the 4th column of the files which is the date column, but It is not working, I am doing exactly what the book says.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong, is it a quote related issue?

Comment: Be more specific than "not working". One problem I see, though, is that you can't just remove the quotes. Quotes are used to allow commas, which otherwise separate two columns, to be used in a value. Removing the quotes prevents you from distinguishing between the two types of commas.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` only accepts one script, while you're giving it two (`{printf $4}` and `$4 ~ /^2012.*/`). Join them into one awk script using awk's `condition { commands }` syntax:

```
sed 's/\"//g' kk.csv  | awk -F ',' '$4 ~ /^2012.*/ {print $4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to use sed. Just awk is enough to search

```
awk -F, '$4 ~ "^\"2012"' kk.csv
```

This will print all line which have 4th column starting with "2012

If you want formatted output(removing quotes etc) awk do that also